# I have this javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, jstl

Someone help me with this. I am doing a maven project and I have included all the required jar files and database url is correct too. I don't know why I am getting this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dospH.png)

I have included mysql/j dependencies in the pom file. And I have also imported the jar files with build path. Below is an image of the dependencies.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al3MD.png)

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        
       <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
    
    <%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
    
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="viewstockcss.css"> 
    <title>View Stock</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="demo">
          <h1>Material Design Responsive Table</h1>
          <h2>Table of my other Material Design works (list was updated 08.2015)</h2>
          
          <div class="table-responsive-vertical shadow-z-1">
          
          <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            
            <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/login" user="admin" password="root"/>
            
            <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${snapshot}">select * from stock</sql:query>
            
            <c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td data-title="ID">value="${item.id}"</td>
                    <td data-title="Name">value="${item.itemname}"</td>
                    <td data-title="Price">value="${item.price}"</td>
                    <td data-title="Status">value="${item.damagestatus}"</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            
            
            
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
                
                    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The StackTrace

```
Jul 30, 2020 8:38:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/virtusa] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/viewstock.jsp] at line [38]

35:         
36:         <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/login" user="root" password="root"/>
37:         
38:         <sql:query var="result" dataSource="${snapshot}">select * from stock</sql:query>
39:         
40:         <c:forEach items="${result.rows}" var="item">
41:             <tr>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ${snapshot}"
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:285)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:168)
    at org.apache.jsp.viewstock_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(viewstock_jsp.java:267)
    at org.apache.jsp.viewstock_jsp._jspService(viewstock_jsp.java:181)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And the POM File

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>virtusa</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>virtusa Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>


    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>virtusa</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post exception stacktrace and your pom.xml as **text**. In any case, the problem is with your data source reference judging by the error message containing `${snapshot}` as the URL.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Hey man I have posted the stacktrace and pom file. I dont understand the problem with the datasource reference .What is wrong there?

Comment: I don't use JSTL myself, but the fact the error message includes the text `${snapshot}` instead of the JDBC url, would indicate that something is wrong with how you reference the data source. I'd recommend checking the documentation for JSTL.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I checked and couldn't find what is wrong with it. Is there any other way to get data from db to jsp other than this method? I dont want to switch from jsp to servlet. I want to stay in the jsp page and retrieve data

Comment: Do EL expressions work in rest of JSP file? The exception message contains an unevaluated EL expression and this strongly suggests that evaluating EL expressions is disabled/deactivated/corrupted in your web application project. On an unrelated note: the JSTL `<sql:xxx>` (and `<xml:xxx>`) tags are highly discouraged since JSP 2.0 (2003). Those should absolutely only be used for prototyping. The proper approach is to use a normal Java class for this logic, starting with a servlet.